# Execute functions just on load

Tags: jquery

How can I make this so that it always works and not only once, everytime the page is loaded?

```
$(function(){

    $('#test').click(function () {
        test();
    });

});

var calledonetime = false;

function test()
{
    if(calledonetime=== false)
    {
        calledonetime = true;
        $('html').css("overflow","hidden");
    }else
    {
        $('html').css("overflow","scroll");
   $('html').css("overflow-x","hidden");
    }

}
```

Comment: Just remove this `$('#test').click(function () {...});`

Comment: The code does not work anymore when I remove this

Comment: Replace `test();` with `$(function(){

    $('#test').click(function () {
        test();
    });

});
`

Comment: And do not forget `$(document).ready(function(){..});`

Comment: This also makes the code stop working

Comment: See this https://jsfiddle.net/uvhb8er1/ see the alert works fine, if your code not working, the problem with your code, not execute whole code on load

Comment: Can you please help me to understand your question? Do you want to call test function on every time user click on #test and also when the page is loading?

Comment: By default my page has overflow:scroll, when you press the button, overflow will be set to hidden and when you press again it will be set to scroll again, with the code in my question it only works once when the page is loaded but it has to work at all times

Answer (score 0):

May this work :

```
var calledonetime = false;
$(function(){ 
    if(calledonetime === false)
    {
        calledonetime = true;
        $('html').css("overflow","hidden");
    }else
    {
        $('html').css("overflow","scroll");
        $('html').css("overflow-x","hidden");
    }
});
```

Comment: This sets overflow to hidden by default but it should be: default: scroll, button pressed is hidden and pressing the button again sets it to default

Comment: it's mean your want change also on button click.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#test').click(function () {
    $('body').toggleClass("sroll");
  });
});
```

in CSS

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}

body.no-scroll {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it: by adding: `calledonetime = false; to else`

```
$(function(){

    $('#test').click(function () {
        test();
    });

});

var calledonetime = false;

function test()
{
    if(calledonetime=== false)
    {
        calledonetime = true;
        $('html').css("overflow","hidden");
    }else
    {
    $('html').css("overflow","scroll");
   $('html').css("overflow-x","hidden");
calledonetime = false;
    }

}
```